# Game Of Life - Out Of Bounds array index

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on the standard Game Of Life program for my Intro to Java course, and so far I've been able to accomplish a lot of it on my own. However, I'm having some difficulty with counting the neighbors of a given cell, to determine whether it lives or dies.

Here is my `countNeighbors` method:

```
public static int countNeighbors(int [][] board, int A, int B) 
{
    int [][]a = board;
    int count = 0;

    if (a[A][B] == 0 || a[A][B] == 1) {
        try{
            if (a[A-1][B-1] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A  ][B-1] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A+1][B-1] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A-1][B  ] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A+1][B  ] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A-1][B+1] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A  ][B+1] == 1) {count++;}
            if (a[A+1][B+1] == 1) {count++;} 
        }

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

    }
    return count;
}
```

When I run my program, this method does not count the neighbors correctly, thus initializing an incorrect new generation. How do I overcome the out of bounds indices of an array?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that `A` and `B` fall within the bounds of the `board` array. Then you should check that adding or subtracting 1 to `A` or `B` keeps you within the bounds of the array.

For example:

```
if (A < a.length && B < a[A].length) {
    if (a[A][B] == 0 || a[A][B] == 1) {
        if (A > 0 && B > 0)
            if (a[A-1][B-1] == 1) {count++;}
        ....
        if (A+1 < a.length && B+1 < a[A].length)
            if (a[A+1][B+1] == 1) {count++;} 
    }
}
```